# vb/c# method can easily add/delete/update recordes from datagridview and textbox control associated with databinding

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net

i ask you if there is any vb/c# method can easily add/delete/update  recordes from datagridview and textbox control associated with databinding of each column in the datatable wich it coming from the dataset without rewrit the hole sql and vb/c# code

```
    Cmd.CommandText = "select * from " & TableName
    Con.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, TableName)
    dt = ds.Tables(TableName)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(TableName)

For Each dc In dt.Columns
Dim txt As TextBox = New TextBox
            txt.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(230, y)
            txt.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 20)
            txt.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", dt, dc.ColumnName.ToString))
            Me.Controls.Add(txt)
Next
```

when i used the mode assistant to generate sqaldataadapter and from the SDA i generate the dataset then i fill it in the load of the form it work as well when i edit the recorde from the datagridview or txtbox and i can navigate throgh the records usind the currencymanager with the BindingContext class but unfortunately in this exemple i only have to create the hole thing with  codes using the WindowsControlLibrary1